# Unity2d: Why does this sprite act like it is behind the background even though its Z-value is set to be in front of the canvas?

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

[Showing the general setup of the scene and where the sprite is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y19uv.png)

[the sprite is "behind" the background but the Z-value should be correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3KwS.png)

I have tried solutions such as changing the render mode of the canvas; the different options do not work and "World Space" turns the game view into the default background color. I could not figure this out after a day of reading up manuals/guides and looking at other questions. Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to use a `SpriteRenderer` on a `Canvas` object. Remove the `SpriteRenderer` and either use an `Image` or `RawImage` component instead.

Another note regarding UI that you will inevitably run into is unless specified otherwise, objects further down in a `Canvas` hierarchy will render on top of those above it.

I would also avoid changing the z-axis on all of your objects. Make `Canvas` groups that have different sorting layers to render groups on top of one another. Place objects in a specific order in the hierarchy to get the draw order you desire. Messing with the z-axis in a 2D scene can be a headache down the line and is not very modular. If you want to change sort order later, the specific z offset you set to each object will need to change.